# How to bind Spy disguises to keys?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-spy

I'm trying to create binds to disguise as all nine classes, but I can't find the commands. `"disguise_Class"` (for example `"disguise_Scout"`) doesn't work.

Because `bind "key" "disguise 8 -2"` can be used to drop the disguise, I expect the other commands to be as cryptic.

My `spy.cfg`, numpad is used and the commands are missing as stated:

```
exec reset

bind "kp_end"
bind "kp_downarrow"
bind "kp_pgdn"
bind "kp_leftarrow"
bind "kp_5" "
bind "kp_rightarrow"
bind "kp_home"
bind "kp_uparrow"
bind "kp_pgup"
bind "kp_ins"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The commands are ([source](https://gamebanana.com/scripts/7198)):

Scout: `"disguise 1 -1"`
Soldier: `"disguise 3 -1"`
Pyro: `"disguise 7 -1"`
Demoman: `"disguise 4 -1"`
Heavy: `"disguise 6 -1"`
Engineer: `"disguise 9 -1"`
Medic: `"disguise 5 -1"`
Sniper: `"disguise 2 -1"`
Spy: `"disguise 8 -1"`

For your config:

```
bind "kp_end" "disguise 1 -1"                
bind "kp_downarrow" "disguise 3 -1"              
bind "kp_pgdn" "disguise 7 -1"                
bind "kp_leftarrow" "disguise 4 -1"              
bind "kp_5" "disguise 6 -1"
bind "kp_rightarrow" "disguise 9 -1"            
bind "kp_home" "disguise 5 -1"                
bind "kp_uparrow" "disguise 2 -1"               
bind "kp_pgup" "disguise 8 -1"
```